# set variable in SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to check whether the user has accepted the speech recognition or not. But for some reason the status is `.authorized` but the according variable won't be changed. What am I missing here? It's not about to display the message to the user, but just for some error handling use cases.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var requestAuth: Bool = false 

init() { 
    SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { (authState) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if authState == .authorized {
                print("is authorized") // <---- is printed!
                self.requestAuth = true
            } else {
                self.requestAuth = false
            }
        }
    }

    if self.requestAuth { // <--- will not be executed - why?
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside the `requestAuthorization` braces ({}) is what's called a `callback` function. Often times, callback functions don't get executed immediately. In fact, the documentation for that function states:

> This method executes asynchronously, returning shortly after you call it

That means that the code that follows will not happen immediately. Similarly, you're using `DispatchQueue.main.async` inside that callback function, which also acts the same way. The code in the braces will not be called right away, so you can't base anything later in your structure on it having happened.

The solution to this is to call any functions that you need that are based on the authorization status from *inside* those closures -- like where you have `print("is authorized")`:

```
init() { 
    SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { (authState) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if authState == .authorized {
                print("is authorized") // <---- is printed!
                self.requestAuth = true
                // do other things based on authorization status
            } else {
                self.requestAuth = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    //can't rely on having an updated value for self.requestAuth here
}
```